# How do you call on a switch case from another class?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to call on a switch case used in another class in a for loop in my java program, however I'm not really sure how to do so.

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
 myView.say( i + "=" + printer.switch(i));
```

This is the loop I have, with the aim being to be able to print out each case in my switch case based on the iteration i. I have played around a bit but can't see to make it work? If anyone could head me in the right direction, that would be great!

Comment: Isn't that switch inside a block (like method..)?

Comment: You can't call a statement from another class, you can only call methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, switch is a flow of control statement and not a method you can call. Wrap your switch code in a method on your object

```
class Printer {
  public String doStuff(int counter){
    switch(counter) {
      case 1:... 
    }
  }
}

myView.say(i+"="+printer.doStuff(i));
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be something like that, thank you very much!